# count characters and add class at certain number

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple input form and want to count characters as user types. On count 10 I would like to add some css. Here is code for counting

```
var count = $('#charCount').text(this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length);
```

Here is a condition which does not work probably wrong syntax?

```
if (count === '10') {
        $('#charCount').css({
            'background-color': 'green'
        });
```

Full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Fv9ug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` in jQuery returns a jQuery object, therefore `count` doesn't store an integer meaning `count === 10` never evaluates to true.

You're also using the `===` strict equality operator which will always return false against `count === '10'` if `count` is supposed to be an integer.

Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myInput').keyup(function() {
        var count = this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;

        $('#charCount').text(count);

        if (count === 10) {
            $('#charCount').css({
                'background-color': 'green'
            });
        } else {
            $('#charCount').css({
                'background-color': 'red'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`length` is a number so it should be

```
if (count === 10) {
```

Comment: even with this, the background-color is not changed.

Comment: @Andrew This doesn't actually matter - `'10'` is cast to an integer (`'10' == 10` evaluates to `true`)

Comment: Yes, but '10' === 10 is false. The OP can decide which approach to take: I have no preference ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;
    $('#charCount').text( count );

    if (count >= 10) {
        $('#charCount').css({
            'background-color': 'green'
        });
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fv9ug/1/

Answer (score 0):

text returns an object, so you cannot read the length correctly from this.